# php parse sdk -> hello world error

Tags: php, sdk, parse-platform

I am using the "Hello World" of [Php Parse Sdk](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/php)

My code:

```
<?php 
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Parse\ParseClient;

ParseClient::initialize('WVqz27oWBfP2weewrfeweKAlVWymjltMGqi9h', 'jgtaXI1Nrim1B4fdnewewewef3iNXgER8y', 'JD8B6dNL9FleweewewhjvvwZwIlc800');

use Parse\ParseObject;

$testObject = ParseObject::create("TestObject");
$testObject->set("foo", "bar");
$testObject->save();

?>
```

and the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Parse\ParseException' with message 'SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate' in C:\xampp\htdocs\parsesdk\vendor\parse\php-sdk\src\Parse\ParseClient.php:250 
Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\parsesdk\vendor\parse\php-sdk\src\Parse\ParseObject.php(915): Parse\ParseClient::_request('POST', '/1/classes/Test...', NULL, '{"foo":"bar"}') 
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\parsesdk\vendor\parse\php-sdk\src\Parse\ParseObject.php(828): Parse\ParseObject::deepSave(Object(Parse\ParseObject)) 
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\parsesdk\index.php(12): Parse\ParseObject->save() 
#3 {main} thrown in  C:\xampp\htdocs\parsesdk\vendor\parse\php-sdk\src\Parse\ParseClient.php on line 250
```

Answer (score 5):

option 1:

You can follow the url http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem to download cacert.pem file. Then go to php.ini set `curl.cainfo = "c:/cacert.pem"`.

option 2:

try to find the code `curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);` in your project then add this code `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);` before.

Comment: I am not using curl at all, so this answer has no value to me, any other suggestions?