# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Parse\ParseException' with message 'SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate'

Tags: php, ssl, parse-platform

This is the first time I use parse.com php SDK and  I try to execute the following code

```
<?php require '../autoload.php'; 
use Parse\ParseObject;
use Parse\ParseClient;
ParseClient::initialize( "Zsr...", "BzM..", "D..." );
$gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
$gameScore->set("score", 1337);
$gameScore->set("playerName", "Sean Plott");
$gameScore->set("cheatMode", false);

try {
        $gameScore->save();
         echo 'New object created with objectId: ' . $gameScore->getObjectId();
        } catch (ParseException $ex) { 
          // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
          // error is a ParseException object with an error code and message.
          echo 'Failed to create new object, with error message: ' + $ex->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

But  I get that error

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Parse\ParseException' with message 'SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/parse/src/Parse/ParseClient.php:250 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/parse/src/Parse/ParseObject.php(925): Parse\ParseClient::_request('POST', '/1/classes/Game...', NULL, '{"score":1337,"...', false) #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/parse/src/Parse/ParseObject.php(836): Parse\ParseObject::deepSave(Object(Parse\ParseObject), false) #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/parse/src/hola.php(11): Parse\ParseObject->save() #3 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/parse/src/Parse/ParseClient.php on line 250
```

The code it's the tutorial code, iI haven't changed anything anyone knows what's the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php parse sdk -> hello world error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25516518/php-parse-sdk-hello-world-error)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I am also getting same issue. Now I resolve using some other forums answer.

Open your ParseClient.php and find:

```
curl_init();
```

And after that add line add:

```
curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

It will work.

Comment: Not but a few months ago I was having a heck of a time with this. Thank you for a quick, simple solution! <3

Comment: Please consider this related answer, as it might be a better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25659839/3562415

Comment: Good solution by turning ssl verifier off. Could have been a disaster in my project if I didn't find this solution