# Save not working to Parse database in PHP

Tags: php, database, parse-platform, save

Im trying to transfer data from my VPS to my Parse database using the following test script. Everything works from creating to setting the object but saving to the database causes a 500 Internal Server Error. I replaced the words "APPLICATION ID" and such with their actual values, and setup Parse according to the quick start guide. Im not sure where the issue could be.

PHP test script

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Parse\ParseClient;
ParseClient::initialize("APPLICATION ID", "REST API KEY","MASTER KEY");
use Parse\ParseObject;
$testObject = ParseObject::create("TestObject");
$testObject->set("foo", "bar");
try {
$testObject->save();
echo 'success';
}
catch (ParseException $ex) {
  echo 'Failed to create new obj, with error message: ' + $ex->getMessage()\;
}?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is a solution but have a look at [php parse sdk -> hello world error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25516518/php-parse-sdk-hello-world-error)